# Update the image height programmatically swift

Tags: swift, image, constraints, height

I have the following hierarchy of views:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUhLs.png).
I need to change the height programmatically (Main Image View Height). Inside feed cell awakeFromNib() I try:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {  
    super.awakeFromNib() 
    mainImageViewHeight.constant = 50
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed after changing Frame

Answer (score -1):

Call `layoutIfNeeded()` after you set constraint's height.